# Null entities in DDD

Tags: c#, null, domain-driven-design, nullable

Take an example of a **Product** entity or aggregate which has a reference to another entity called **Category**. Before a domain event like **CategorizeProduct** happens, the Category's state is empty. To represent that in C#, I have to use `NULL`. I can't use `Nullable<T>` in C# because that can be used for value types only.

Is using `NULL` in DDD an anti-pattern? Some of the solutions that have been suggested are to (1) use `MayBe<T>` (2) use a [collection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/04/TheBCLalreadyhasaMaybemonad/) in the place of single entity.

`MayBe<t>` is an option, but is there a different approach to handle Empty entity state in DDD?

Comment: Maybe<T> adds nothing that a null check doesn't offer. A collection for a single entity would be a poor solution as well. It's a null check, it's not the end of the world. If the reference has no value by definition then there is nothing wrong with representing that as `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these types of things you can use the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). Think of e.g. the `String.Empty` property as a simple case of that.

If your `null` object should have different behavior for some of it's methods, you make it a private inner class that derives from `Category` and overrides specific behaviors.

For your `Category`:

```
public class Category
{
    private class UnassignedCategory : Category
    {
        public UnassignedCategory() : base("") { }
    }

    private static readonly UnassignedCategory _unassigned = new UnassignedCategory();

    public static Category Unassigned 
    { 
        get { return _unassigned; }
    }

    public Category(string name) 
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool IsAssigned 
    {
        get { return ReferenceEquals(this, _unassigned); }
    }
}
```

Note that in the example above, since a default parameterless constructor on `Category` is not present, and there is no way to change the `Name` property's value, a subclass was not really needed, we could have simply used a static `Category` instance.

Usage:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Category = Category.Unassigned;
        // other stuff
    }

    // other stuff.

    public void AssignCategory(Category category) 
    {
        // Any associated logic.
        Category = category;
    }
    public Category Category { get; private set; } 
}
```

If you are saving and loading `null` (i.e. Unassigned) categories from the database, you may want to use a variation on this theme, with an explicit (immutable) id/attribute for "unassigned" that is saved together with other `Category` attributes and used in the `IsAssigned` check.

**Viable Alternative**

A completely viable alternative is to just to keep doing what you are doing now, using a `null` reference. You can add some extension methods to make life easier for you if needed.

```
public static MyCategoryExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this Category category) 
    {
        return category == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(category.Name);
    }
    public static Category EmptyIfNull(this Category category) 
    {
        return category ?? new Category("");
    }
    public static Category DefaultIfNullOrEmpty(this Category category) 
    {
        return category.IsNullOrEmpty() 
            ? new Category(Category.DefaultName)
            : category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your concern - NULL could mean the category was not loaded yet or could mean that there is no category assigned yet.

An option is to add a nullable property CategoryId, which contains the ID of the category that was assigned. If a category is assigned, the ID is always filled in, else it is null. This means that if CategoryID is filled in and Category is null, then a category was assigned but not loaded.

This approach fits naturally if you use Entity Framework to load or persist your domain.

```
 public class Product
 {
      public Product()
      {
          // validate entity 
      }

      public int? CategoryId { get; private set; }
      public Category Category { get; private set; } 
 }
```